# Link with SDL using Cocotron CDT

Tags: linux, macos, sdl, ld, cocotron

I'm trying to use Cocotron to compile for Linux in Xcode. Everything's working great with Foundation, but I'm trying to also use SDL. I've copied the libraries over from Linux (Ubuntu) but I'm having trouble linking.

Despite copying libpulse-simple over as well (and placing it in every directory I thought would possibly make sense), I was still unable to remove this error:

```
warning: libpulse-simple.so.0, needed by /Developer/Cocotron/1.0/Linux/i386/Frameworks//libSDL-1.2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Comment: Install Linux in a VM and build there :)

Comment: That's how I test! But Cocotron isn't really designed to be built on Linux (unless I've misunderstood); it's for cross-compilation from Xcode. Because of this, I started with GNUstep, but was really unimpressed (even basic Obj-C that only used Foundation had to be dramatically altered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: explicitly add "Other Linker Flag"s for every dependency of SDL. For anyone else trying to do this, that's:

```
-lFLAC -lnsl -logg -lvorbis -lvorbisenc -ldbus -lsndfile -luuid -lwrap -lXau -lXdmcp -lXext -lXi -lxcb -lXtst -lX11-xcb -lxcb-atom -lSM -lrt -lpulsecommon -lSDL -lpulse -lpulse-simple -lX11 -lICE
```